# Which SOpedians are spending too many cycles on MSO?

Tags: reputation, discussion, data-analysis

A while back on the SO podcast, Joel Spolsky basically called folks who spend lots of time on MSO losers.  He has a point, to a certain extent, I think.  A little bit of meta is OK, too much and one becomes the teacher's pet.

So I whipped up a graph this morning and concentrated the data points on the page 1 MSO users.  *(Spent way too much time, 2/3rds of the total, labeling the graph with names--not doing that again in future graphs.)*  The below graph has three axises:

- ***x*-axis:** MSO reputation points
- ***y*-axis:** SO reputations points (SU in the case of Diago)
- ***z*-axis:** SO profile views

Moderators have an excuse for spending time on MSO, the rest of us are just being nerdy.  That is why I have segregated them into their own series.

*(Why profile views?  You're all a bunch of narcissistic tools, and we all know it!  You like this kind of stuff.)*

[link text http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/MSO-rep-versus-SO-rep-small.gif](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/MSO-rep-versus-SO-rep-small.gif)

What does this tell us?  Well, the users with the lowest slope are the SOpedians who are spending too much time on MSO and neglecting SO/SF/SU.  To continue Jeff's *"MSO is the teacher's lounge"* analogy, these users are the *Teacher's pets.*  The top three SOpedians with very low slopes:

1. Ian Elliott (0.30)
2. random (0.32)
3. John Smithers (0.33)

Thoughts?  Criticisms?  Requests?  Other interpretations?  Let the waffles flow.

---

*Updated with graph as per request:*

- ***x*-axis:** MSO reputation points
- ***y*-axis:** SO reputations points (SU in the case of Diago)
- ***z*-axis:** SO Profile views / account age

I did not bother with labels...too time consuming and the bubbles have not moved, just changed size.  (Most of you are in at 11 or 12 months.)  I also made Jeff Atwood transparent so that he does not block TheTXI.  (Can you hear the ponies singing in heaven now?)

[alt text http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/MSO-rep-versus-SO-rep-over-age-small.gif](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/MSO-rep-versus-SO-rep-over-age-small.gif)

Comment: w00t I'm in a graph. that's neat :D

Comment: I have a disproportionate amount of profile views. This your fault somehow, Ólafur.

Comment: You're the sun everybody is revolving around in that strange solar system.

Comment: Look at me, swallowing jjnguy like a woman swallows a spider to catch a fly.

Comment: That random, what a loser.

Comment: I realise you'd have to do all that awesome hand drawing again, but could you add the page 1 SO users too? :)

Comment: Welbog is the areola to jjinguy?

Comment: I'm his penumbra.

Comment: @Greg: it was painless to add you since your data point is in the middle of no where.  I just pasted it into the image, so there you go :)

Comment: Can someone create a graph that has my name in it?

Comment: Where is TheTXI?

Comment: @random: Good catch...TheTXI is under Jeff.

Comment: I would hardly consider myself a delicate flower if you payed attention at all, but then again I consider you a bigot so I guess it's all the same.

Comment: I didn't make the cut =(

Comment: Woot! I'm in a graph! But why aren't you bastards looking at my profile? Because then you'll be all, "This guy does business intelligence? I need that! My business is unintelligent! And I love this guy! I'm calling." And I'd really appreciate that. Chiefly because it will allow me to buy more waffles.

Comment: @Ian Elliott: *"Bigot?"*  You'll have to explain that one...it's lost on me.  I repeat, you are taking this all *way* too seriously.  And follow random's fine example.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not on that graph.

Comment: This graph reveals to me that we need to do a better job of promoting Welbog's profile. http://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog

Comment: Hmm profile view / account age seems to be the same proportion as profile view

Comment: Hmm Welbog: 1361 views. My profile 1575 views. Why is his bubble so big?

Comment: Grrrr....I did not do a sanity check on the profile views...Crap.  I have an extra digit in Welbog's profile value (13544).

Comment: I know realize that *Bill the Lizard* is a very funny guy.  Ha ha.  Anyway, the second graph is updated.  Not going to update the first.  All those  penumbra should never have happened.  *Sigh*...

Comment: I have shrunken.

Comment: Cool. I like the middle of nowhere.

Comment: If these graphs indicate *anything*, it's that Skeet is wholly unnatural. Hemp-wearing hippies everywhere should be protesting in front of his office...

Comment: I feel so inferior to Welbog...

Comment: @Welbog I have made you smaller!

Comment: I knew it was your fault.

Comment: All this has proven is that I spend **way** to much time in front of my computer. No wonder my wife gives me dirty looks when I mention SU.

Comment: I'm not only in a graph, I'm one of the top 3 losers! It's like in PE back in school ;)

Comment: Needs to be updated...

Comment: What makes one a "SOPedian"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would replace profile views with:

```
profile views / account age
```

Comment: there ya go!

Comment: Cool. I was trying to figure out why mine didn't change but then I realized I joined relatively early but didn't really start answering questions (in earnest) until December.

Answer (score 4):

I reckon it's because you can get away with a lot more off topic stuff here. Noisy comments and posts just get pruned ASAP from S[OFU] but here? Whammy, they're in your face and making noise like kids in a candy store.

Someone posts something, the kids start making off the wall comments, and before you know it, someone's come up with the next Jon Skeet Facts, or whatever.

[Un?]Fortunately, the sheer noise in comments also leads to some very helpful discussion and some great topics, so it would be stupid to start pruning it all willy nilly.

Comment: It is far more relaxed in Meta than it is out in the regular SOFU.

Comment: @random - relaxed != (noise || mayhem) though.

Comment: @Kev: relaxed != (!noise && !mayhem) though

Answer (score 3):

How about replacing profile views with account age? (How long they have been a member of the site)

Comment: But how many of the Meta losers put in their real or approximate age?

Comment: Account age. How long they have been a member of the site.

Answer (score 3):

ServerFault, **n**o idea. StackOv**e**rflow, way too slow. SuperUs**e**r, getting there, but knowle**d**ge of computers isn't that broad. Need more Opera questions.

Where is the z-axis?

If you want to go with **m**ore waffles, replace the chicken p**o**x ma**r**ks with waffles and the smallpox d**e**nts with drops of syrup.

For those not so qui**c**k on the draw at SO, how about rep**l**acing that number w**i**th th**e**ir highest rep value if it happe**n**s **t**o be, oh, maybe SF or **S**U?

Hang on, is this an intervention?

Comment: It's in your face!

Comment: The z-axis is the bubble size

Comment: So a small bubble face means you're flying under the radar? Veddy swell.

Comment: A small bubble means that nobody cares about your existence, even yourself.  (Viewing your own profile increments the count.)

Comment: Not raising any ire or causing any interest, excellent indeed.

Comment: Viewing your own profile doesn't increment the count anymore

Comment: Cool.  When did that happen?

Comment: @Random: I did try to select the highest score of all S* sites for folks.  The only person who had that happen was Diego.  (If you see an error in my data there, let me know and I'll investigate.)

Comment: Can't quite work out what the rep for the non-meta is for #6. If it's under 1K, that's SO. If it's closer to 1.5K, that the SU data.

Comment: I'm not getting you: Which users are you talking about?  I'll go revisit the numbers.

Comment: So close to the zero line, hard to tell if you're using SU rep or SO rep for #6 (random).

Comment: I could not find your user on SU, only SO.  The number there is 963.  What is your user ID on SU?

Comment: On second thought, let's just leave it alone, might de-slope the current slide.

Comment: It would drop you out of the #2 Teacher's Pet ranking, and then I could not use you as a fine example for Ian Elliott to follow.  Your call.  ;)

Comment: @random: What sort of clients?

Comment: Need more cents?

Comment: @gnovice web devving in PHP. But this isn't the place to bring up those kind of subliminal messages.