# Sizes and overlaps of communities on the sites

Tags: discussion, tags, data-dump, statistics, graphs

This might be totally useless, but I wanted to join the league of people who use the Google chart API and the data dump to create pretty pictures.

So I took a look at the relative sizes of the "communities" on the site, i.e. the numbers of users who are active in certain tags, and also how much the communities overlap. A user is considered a member of a tag's community if they have at least three questions or answers in the tag. Quality (i.e. post scores) doesn't count; this is **solely about the number of users**.

Examples:

[image: what's with pyqt?] [image: the center is where the flame wars start] [image: so, what exactly is the performance of a secure sql-server?] [image: this is from the April datadump -- there'll be more unicorns in May]

Thoughts? Any three-combinations you'd like to see?

---

"The three C's" as per Koper's request and the three ancients for Pollyanna:

[image: it's just a letter] [image: yep, it's not a lot]

---

You can see additional graphs as requested by other users below. Note that this is several years old (and I have long stopped updating this).

Comment: The three C's: [C#, c++, c]

Comment: Cobol, fortran, and lisp, please.

Comment: How about C# vs. Java and Objective C?

Comment: Not a single person knows fortran lisp and cobol?!

Comment: No single user has submitted an answer in all three tags.  Given the rarity of such questions, I suspect it's more an issue of timing when they are around rather than no user exists on SO that couldn't answer all three.  However, you can fix this - go answer one of each of the questions, and ask him to re-run his graph on the next data dump...

Comment: @Pollyanna: It has to be at least three, which proves your point even more so. There's some overlap when I decrease the threshold to 1.

Comment: No one with good ideas for SU or SF?

Comment: @balpha - Ah, yes, I forgot about the minimum of three.  Hmm, ideas for SU and SF...

Comment: I agree, Objective-C would be nice to see in the same graph as the Three Big C's. (Can the script not do 4?) It would be humbling, kind of like stepping into the Ultimate Perspective Vortex... ;-)

Comment: very cool, any chance you could either release the source or put it up on app engine or something?

Comment: ASP, JSP, PHP.... Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer

Comment: @Quinn: The script will do 4 without a problem, but the google chart API won't.

Comment: @cobbal re source: There's no black magic involved; I just query the stuff from the data dump as described. I could put it somewhere, but you'll probably be faster writing it yourself than reading my code ;) I'll see what I'll do. Re app engine: See my comment on Adrian's answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36683

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36754/sizes-and-overlaps-of-search-for-skills-on-careers

Comment: I love this question. Very interesting to see the patterns of the various communities. Sad that some are so small that results are meaningless. Also, unfortunate to be limited to three at a time. Now I want an apple pie of all JVM languages (and I mean all :).

Comment: *"@Quinn: The script will do 4 without a problem, but the google chart API won't."* I b believe it goes deeper than that: that generally you can only do N+1 sets in a N dimensional representation. Have to think about it.

Comment: @dmckee: Even deeper than that. In general, you can do more, but only if you use other shapes than circles (see the canonical http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram for example pictures). Staying with circles, you can actually only do *two* in general. Look at http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=v&chd=t:100,100,60,0,30,30,0&chs=300x200&chdl=female|male|adults -- every adult is either male or female, but this is impossible to show with circles. Google does its best, but for these corner cases, it has to fail.

Comment: Now that the Meta dump is available, still can't think of distinct groups/communities to compare since it's all a grab bag.

Comment: @random: My thoughts exactly.

Comment: Can you share the script? I would be interested to play a bit with it. I am also interested in how topics overlap across different StackExchange sites.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to see this for different tags at economics.stackexchange

Comment: @FooBar This is an almost six years old topic, I've stopped adding new stuff a long time ago, sorry.

Answer (score 14):

That's great!

Here's one for:

- Django
- Ruby on Rails
- ASP.NET MVC

[image: probably looks a lot like the ruby-python-c# graph]

Answer (score 14):

Here's one for:

- subjective
- not-programming-related
- fun

Just so we can see if the same bunch of people is responsible for all the screwing around. ;)

[image]

Comment: note that *all* funny non-programmers are also subjective

Comment: not-programming-related is often slapped on posts when users don't know to flag/vote to close; I wish it could be banned.

Answer (score 12):

Scripting languages.... fight!

perl vs python vs ruby

---

[image] [image]

Comment: Add shell, then.

Comment: Wow, never shall the powershell and applescript groups meet.

Answer (score 11):

For alex:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The objective c community is larger than expected. I wonder if the iPhone has anything to do with it.

Comment: I like that I (should be) in a very tiny sliver of this Venn -- the Obj-C/C# overlap. :)

Answer (score 11):

PHP Javascript and HTML Anyone?

I bet it will just be a single circle :)

---

Well … almost:

[image] [image]

Comment: More like CSS JS HTML

Answer (score 10):

### SF:

Windows, Linux, Macosx

Apache, IIS

MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server

DNS, IIS, PHP

[image] [image]

---

### SU:

Windows, Linux, OSX

Harddrive, video, ram

Monitor, Multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Firefox, google-chrome, ie

OSX, USB, PDF

[image] [image]

Answer (score 10):

The JVM languages:

1. Java
2. Scala
3. Clojure
4. Groovy

Limiting to three is hard. Leave Java out, I guess.

Then the following, perhaps with either Java or the biggest community from above.

5. JRuby
6. Jython

Finally, the following two, with either Clojure or Scala.

7. Haskell
8. Erlang

---

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 8):

Cool.

How about RIA technologies?

Silverlight vs Flash vs Air

---

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here's a few I found interesting:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 7):

Is it possible to do a "starts with" on these?

If so, to clarify a slice in alex's request, I'd like to see an [objective-c]/[iphone-*]/[cocoa] breakout.

---

Your wish is my command:

[image: it's all about that iThingadongdong]

Comment: So objective c would be almost absent on SO without iPhone?

Comment: @alex - Not necessarily, but almost all people knowing objective c are concerned about iphone, according to the protocol here and this graph

Answer (score 7):

Very cool.  How about...

1. security & cryptography & C# (for size comparison)
2. WPF & silverlight & Winforms

---

[image] [image]

Comment: got a third one for WPF? Google only does 3-part venn diagrams.

Comment: @balpha - winforms?

Comment: I find it interesting that so many people in crypto are also in C#.  I would have expected a much lower percentage.

Comment: Interesting that wpf appears to be as popular as winforms.

Comment: Well, "popular" is a bit misleading here. It's more about Questions asked. I'm making an unjustified, general, non-scientific, subjective statement: The popularity/usage of WinForms is much much higher, but WPF being such a different technology requires relatively much more questions than the rather straight forward WinForms.

Answer (score 7):

My third and probably last request :P

`jquery` and `javascript`

---

I threw in IE to have a third one:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

haskell lisp f#

C++ Java C#

:-)

thanks man!

---

[image] [image]

Answer (score 7):

[Apple] vs. [Google] vs. [Microsoft]

---

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: On what site?``

Comment: Okay, I did all three. But note that those aren't good community size measuring tags.

Comment: Wow... no intersection...

Comment: @Daniel - small sample size.

Answer (score 5):

Great idea!

C#, ASP.NET, WinForms

---

[image]

Comment: interesting that more than half the winforms questions also involve asp.net

Comment: These are users active in the different tags, not questions in multiple tags.  This shows us that many people who are active in the winforms tag are also active in the asp.net tag.

Answer (score 5):

ASP/ASP.NET vs PHP

---

[image]

Comment: I didn't expect it to be bigger. Is that representative, or just the general MS bias as both Joel and Jeff use MS languages, I wonder?

Answer (score 5):

how about:

.NET, Mono, ASP.NET

.NET, VB.NET, C#

---

[image] [image]

Comment: I was waiting to see one with c# and vb.net.

Answer (score 5):

How about databases/platforms

C#|VB.NET|.NET, Sql Server, Oracle

Java, Oracle, Sql Server

C++, Oracle, Sql Server

C#, Java, Sql Server

C#, Java, Oracle

PHP, Oracle, MySQL

(I think C# should be C# or VB.NET or .NET, I don't know about java)

MySQl, Oracle, Sql Server (on stackoverflow, as a control for the above)

---

Sorry for the color mixup, but with all those wishes, it was pretty hard to keep a consistent ordering:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: That's a neat idea! The last one (for SF, though) is already done, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36590/sizes-and-overlaps-of-communities-on-the-sites/36668#36668

Comment: @balpha I was thinking of it for stack overflow

Comment: thanks,
so mysql goes with php most of the time
but java does not seem to go with oracle (not what I was expecting), it looks like more oracle people are using .net than java.

Answer (score 5):

Most popular js libraries (according to tag counts on SO)

- jQuery
- Prototype
- Dojo

redhat flavors (on SF)

- redhat
- fedora
- centos

I was gonna suggest ubuntu variants (kubuntu, xubuntu, etc) but other than ubuntu those tags are pretty scarce.

---

[image] [image]

Comment: There are four (4) users in the intersection of all three JS libraries, including cletus and Mister "The <center> cannot hold" bobince.

Answer (score 4):

I'd quite like to see the overlap of users between the sites - who's active on SO, SF & SU (and meta?) generally, not in particular tags. Given that over all of recorded history this might be quite large, perhaps restrict it to the last week/month/quarter.

Comment: The data dump doesn't include account associations, so there's no good way to cross-reference users between sites. Meta isn't in the data dump at all.

Comment: Sounds like Stu needs an update: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18737/who-spends-too-much-time-on-meta @bal

Comment: This is what I thought the question was about when I read the title...

Answer (score 4):

How about Android, iPhone, Windows-Mobile

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Windows automation languages (on Stack Overflow and Server Fault):

- PowerShell
- VBScript
- Batch

---

*Note:* If you notices discrepancies regarding the numbers for previously posted graphs and these ones, that's because these two are the first graphs based on the February 2010 data dump.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, it doesn't look like it would be very hard to write a small web utility that let people put in their own choice of 2+ tags and have this auto-generated, instead of having this flood of requests. Show me the link to the data dump and I'll do it.

This could be a lot of fun and an interesting new use for SO.

**EDIT:** Ah, found it. I'll see what I can whip up :) Any other suggestions for types of charts that people would want?

Comment: No, it's probably not very hard. I just didn't feel like optimizing for a web-app kind of situation (You'll either have a lot of preprocessing, or restrict the requests to certain tags, or be too slow for real-time response).

Comment: Also, I didn't expect Jeff to tweet this -- It pushed the number of requests quite a bit. http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/8087621756

Comment: Where did you find it?

Answer (score 3):

I'd love to see Apache, nginx, lighttpd. Thanks.

---

[image]

Comment: How about add IIS?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to follow up [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36590/sizes-and-overlaps-of-communities-on-the-sites/36703#36703) with a comparison relative to Java. So, picking Java, the largest jvm language (apparently), and the smallest jvm language (of those I listed):

1. Java
2. Scala
3. jRuby

---

It almost makes you feel sorry:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can you do ORs?

`css || html || javascript || web-development` plus `c || c++`

---

[image]

Comment: Not yet, maybe later. I still need a third one, though.

Comment: How about `java || .net` for the third one?

Comment: Note that a user who has exactly one post in each of [css], [html], and [javascript] tags, has three posts in the combined tag soup and is thus considered part of the community.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm curious about the relative community sizes:

- matlab
- java
- .net

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about some size/overlap comparisons of managed languages on JVM and .NET?

For the JVM, how about: java, scala, clojure, rhino, jruby, jython.

For .NET: c#, f#, ironpython, powershell, boo, nemerle.

(I ask rather greedily, as it'd be cool to put in my slides when talking about Scala next month.)

[image] [image]

Comment: I suggested something similar. But Groovy must appear in any JVM language comparison.

Comment: see Daniel's answer for more JVM stuff: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36590/sizes-and-overlaps-of-communities-on-the-sites/36703#36703 Also, c# is too big and nemerle is too small in relationship to the other .net ones.

Answer (score 2):

As someone in the unfortunate position of programming in ColdFusion, I'd like to see these tags compared:

- coldfusion
- php
- asp

---

[image]

Comment: There you go (or did you mean asp.net?)

Comment: @balpha: not sure really, i was just throwing out a third option. php and coldfusion are the only webapp environments i use.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Game development related:

- game-development
- opengl
- directx

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Well, I'm surprised they're not more inclusive of game-dev.

Answer (score 1):

[C++] vs. [Java] vs. [language-agnostic]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Databases:

- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- Oracle

Webservers:

- Apache
- IIS
- lighthttpd

Python implementations:

- Python
- IronPython
- Jython

---

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

compare versions of visual studio.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any way to show the overlap of users between the StackExchange Sites? I think it would be interesting to see these charts comparing SO, SO Meta, SU, and SF

Comment: The data dump doesn't include account associations, so there's no good way to cross-reference users between sites. Meta isn't in the data dump at all.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms

---

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea WPF and WinForms were so similarly popular.

Comment: Actually, those two had already been compared: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36590/sizes-and-overlaps-of-communities-on-the-sites/36620#36620

Answer (score 1):

PHP, MySQL, WinForms

We'll see if a prospective employer will go crazy looking for someone with all of these skills.

Edit: I now have a good argument to apply! Thanks.

---

[image]

Comment: You might still have to find an employer that acutally *needs* php and winforms skills :)

Comment: @balpha: Haha, actually, now that I re-read what I wrote, it's ambiguous. I'm strong on WinForms and weak on PHP. They're looking for someone with WinForms + SQL Server + PHP + MySQL, and the graph here shows that they could be in la-la land. So I might as well give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

- `career-development` vs `project-management` vs `best-practices` on SO
- `virtualbox` vs `vmware.*` vs `.*kvm` on SF
- `vim | vi` vs `emacs.*` vs `notepad++` on SU
- `retagging` vs `editing` vs `moderation` on MSO

Pretty please?

---

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: [this guy](http://superuser.com/users/1931) is the vi/np++ overlap

Answer (score 1):

Java Implementation

netbeans, eclipse, intellij

Comment: Sorry, I have long stopped updating this. This post is almost three years old.

Answer (score 1):

CPU architecture

- ARM
- X86
- MIPS

Comment: Sorry, I have long stopped updating this. This post is almost three years old.

Answer (score 0):

You probably now have better ways to spend your time but...

- StackOverflow, Programmers and Theoretical Computer Science
- SuperUser, AskUbuntu and Unix
- Board and Card Games, Role Playing Games and Gaming
- Maths, Stats and Tex

Answer (score -1):

Why only three?

I would like to see the top 10 on the [TIOBE index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) That's:

- Java
- C
- C++
- PHP
- (Visual) Basic
- C#
- Python
- Perl
- Objective-C
- Delphi

Comment: Okay, you go ahead and teach google (and the universe) to display 10-set venn diagrams; I'll do the rest :)