# Sizes and overlaps of search for skills on careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs, fun

The graphic on [Sizes and overlaps of communities on the sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36590/sizes-and-overlaps-of-communities-on-the-sites/36753#36753) are very interesting, can we have the same for “wanted” skills on careers.

E.g If I already know x and y what should I learn next…

we don't see a full data dump for this just

- Employer  id -> all tags searched for
- CV id -> all tags of each time (e.g. separate hate / love)
- No need for any other data, however location would be interesting as well.

Comment: hehe... I don't think Jeff's gonna give us the careers data dump :)